# get the index of the products page (when browsing category catalog)

Tags: magento-1.9, catalog, url, product-list

What's the best way to get the index of the products page we are currently on?

what I mean is this:

[image]

Note: theoratically I could get it by parsing the URL and get the param from there (eg get the p=2 from url */magento/men/pants-denim.html?p=2*), but I want a 'clean' way that will have less chance to collide with other extensions.

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself. You can get this with:

```
Mage::getBlockSingleton('page/html_pager')->getCurrentPage();
```